# c++ cin input not working?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Car{
    std::string model;
    unsigned int year;
};

int main(){
    using namespace std;

    int carNum;
    cout << "How many cars do you wish you catalog? ";
    cin >> carNum;
    Car * cars = new Car[carNum];

    for (int i=0;i<carNum;i++){
        cout << "Car #" << i << endl;
        cout << "Please enter the make: ";
        getline(cin, cars[i].model);

        cout << "Please enter the year made: ";
        cars[i].year = cin.get();
    }

    cout << "Here's your collection" << endl;

    for (int i=0;i<carNum;i++){
        cout << cars[i].model << " " << cars[i].year << endl;
    }

    delete [] cars;

    return 0;
}
```

When i execute the program, the `getline(cin, car[i].model)` just get skipped over. Why is this?

like this:

> ```
> Car #2
> Please enter the make: Please enter the year made:
> ```

Comment: What do you mean skipped over?

Comment: You need to be more clear when you say it "just gets skipped over". It's almost certain that the code is getting executed. Please describe the *symptoms* is cars[i].model always empty?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simple reason.

When you do `cin >> whatever`, a `\n` is left behind (it was added when you pressed Enter). By default, `getline` reads until the next `\n`, so the next read will simply read an empty string.

The solution is to discard that `\n`. You can do it by putting this:

```
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');
```

Just after the `cin >> carNum`.

Don't forget to include `limits` in order to use `numeric_limits`.

Comment: Oh yeah. I could also do `(cin >> carNum).get();`

Comment: Or if you don't wish to be obnoxiously pedantic, you may write a reasonably large number instead of numeric_limits blah blah max.

Comment: @Zac the trouble with not being pedantic OS that the code will break at some point. It may not matter here because o the simplicity of the program but the habit of pedantic is one we need to encourage not scorn as I will matter one day.

Comment: @ultimate buster. What happens if I type '34 <enter>' now your get reads the space and the code breaks.

Answer (score 0):

After every cin call using insertion operator. You must call `cin.ignore()` if you want `cin.getline ()` to work.

As cin>> leaves behind a '\n' character when you press enter and because of that when you use getline () it picks up the `\n`
and takes no input as it finds `\n` in the input stream which is the default delimiter.

So you can either do `cin.ignore ()` after every cin>> or simply set a delimiter character `cin.getline ()`

Comment: How is this answer different than the one by @EtienneDeMartel from May 4 '11 at 1:14?