# cin.getline() is not working after cin

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [c++ cin input not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5877420/c-cin-input-not-working)

I have been trying to input a string after an integer using the following code in c++.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
using namespace std;
int main(){
     int n;
     char inp[10];
     cin>>n;
     //fflush(stdin);
     cin.getline(inp,10);
     cout<<inp;
     return 0;
}
```

When i am compiling and running above code, the program is prompting for input only once and printing nothing. I am using g++ for compiling the code.
Also when i uncommented the line

```
fflush(stdin)
```

(clearing input buffer), the o/p of program remains the same. I don't understand what is going on here.

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` is undefined behaviour. Anyway, look at some of the related questions on the right, and I also suggest using `std::string`, which allows for any size of line and extra flexibility, ease of use, and safety.

Comment: Don't use member `getline`. Use the free function `std::getline` instead (from `<string>`).

Comment: The program in the question doesn't "prompt" at all. The only output by the program is the one single `cout` before the `return`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

 int n;
 char inp[10];
 cin>>n;
 cin.get();//cin.get(); just waits for enter. more approprate for this would be cin.ignore(); because it will flush the input stream for cin.
 cin.getline(inp,10);
 cout<<inp;
 // cin.get(); you could use this so your program wont return0 and close right away.
return 0;
}//tested in this config it works as desired, good luck
```