# why input causes problem to my do/while menu

Tags: c++, command-line, do-while, cin

I am trying to write a program with the menu using do/while.
As first step i am entering command line argument in parentheses, example "some text here", and get a C-style string. On each case my program should call a specific function on that string.

The problem is, that one of my functions using a user input `cin.getline()`. When I am calling it and trying to type in a new string to replace the previous one, my program takes this string as a choices in a menu.

The main function:

```
char newArray[100]{};
int choice{0};
do {
    cin >> choice;
    switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            functionF(argv[1], newArray);
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << argv[1] << endl;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "wtf";
    }
} while (choice != 3);
```

And a function:

```
void functionF(char *ptr, char newArray[]) {
    cin.getline(newArray, 100);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        ptr[i] = newArray[i];
        if (newArray[i] == '\0')
            break;
    }
}
```

Without do/while menu function works fine.

Input example : command-line input "text sample",
Now `argv[1]` is this C-style string. If i type 2, the program outputs `argv[1]`, when I press 1 I expect program to take another C-style string as user input. But when I am trying to input new string my program takes my input like (`cin >> choice`), for example I am trying to type "new text is here", and my program have to change `argv[1]` for this line but it takes this input as (`cin >> choice`).

Comment: It's unclear what is happening. Please post the sample input, the output that you get and the output that you expect.

Comment: edited question with sample

Comment: I don't see `argv[1]` being used in the code in the post.

Comment: yes, it was argv[0] but it's not the problem, the problem is that my second input cin.getline() count as first input cin >> choice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cin.getline() is not working after cin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14552688/cin-getline-is-not-working-after-cin)

Comment: @kiner_shah, yes, you was right, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
void functionF(char *ptr, char newArray[]) {
    cin.ignore();                  //add this line to fix an error
    cin.getline(newArray, 100);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        ptr[i] = newArray[i];
        if (newArray[i] == '\0')
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain what you changed and how it solves the problem.