# I cannot figure out why my code won't get past the cin on line 60. Help?? c++

Tags: c++, struct, cin

This program should be accepting a bet, generating a set of cards for each player, and adding the bet to the winner's pool. This is a class project.  I cannot figure out what the problem is on line 60.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

struct cards {

    int value;
    string face;
    string suit;
    bool facebool;
};

struct hand {

    cards card[4];
    int antiduplicate[52];
};

struct player {

    string name;
    int sum;
    int money;  
    hand hand;
    int bet;
};

struct points {
    int player1;
    int player2;
};

hand drawhand(int [52]);
points calcvalue(player, player);
int winner(player, player);

int main() {
    points store = {};
    player house = {"The House"};
    player player1 = {};

    srand (time(0));


    cout << "Enter player 1's name:";
            getline(cin,player1.name);

    cout << "Enter player 1's money:";
            cin >> player1.money;
        cout << endl;
        house.money = (player1.money + 1);
do{     

        int deckarray[52] = {0};
        //do{

                cout << "What do you want to bet?\n";
/* line 60 */ cin >> player1.bet;
                cout << "check";
                if (player1.bet < player1.money){

                }
                else if (player1.bet > player1.money){
                    cout << "\nYou cannot go into debt!!\n";
                }
                else if (player1.bet == 0){
                    cout << "\nYou ended the game!";
                    return 0;
                }

            //}while (bet > player1.money);

    house.hand = drawhand(deckarray);
        for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
            if (house.hand.antiduplicate[i] == 1)
            deckarray[i] = 1;
        }
    player1.hand = drawhand(deckarray);
        for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
            if (player1.hand.antiduplicate[i] == 1)
            deckarray[i] = 1;
        }
        cout << "\nCheck check\n";

    store = calcvalue(player1, house);
    player1.sum = store.player1;
    house.sum = store.player2;

    cout << player1.name << "'s hand:\n" << player1.hand.card[1].face << " of " <<player1.hand.card[1].suit << endl
     << player1.hand.card[2].face << " of " <<player1.hand.card[2].suit << endl <<player1.hand.card[3].face << " of " <<player1.hand.card[3].suit << endl;
            cout << ">> " <<player1.name <<  " scored " << player1.sum << " points!\n\n";



        cout << house.name << "'s hand:\n" << house.hand.card[1].face << " of " <<house.hand.card[1].suit << endl
             << house.hand.card[2].face << " of " <<house.hand.card[2].suit << endl <<house.hand.card[3].face << " of " <<house.hand.card[3].suit << endl;
                    cout << ">> " << house.name <<  " scored " << house.sum << " points!\n";
    int win;
    win = winner(player1, house);

    if (win == 1){
        cout << "\n" << player1.name << " wins the round!!" << endl;
        player1.money = (player1.money + player1.bet);          house.money = (house.money - player1.bet);
    }
    else if (win == -1){    
        cout << "\n\n" << house.name << " wins the round!!";
        house.money = (house.money + player1.bet);
        player1.money = (player1.money - player1.bet);
    }
    else if (win == 0){
            cout << "\n\n" << house.name << " wins the round!!";
            house.money = (house.money + player1.bet);
            player1.money = (player1.money - player1.bet);
    }

        cout << endl << "House money: " << house.money << endl << "Player money: " << player1.money << endl << endl;


}while (player1.money > 0 && house.money > 0 && player1.bet != 0);
    cout << "Game over!";

return 0;
}

hand drawhand(int deckarray[52])
{
string tsuit, tface;
    int tvalue;
    int suitvalue, facevalue;
    bool tfacebool;
    hand thand;



    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
    if (deckarray[i] == 1)
    thand.antiduplicate[i] = 1;
    }
    int index;

    do {

    index = rand()%52;  

    } while (thand.antiduplicate[i] == 1);

    thand.antiduplicate[i] = 1;
    facevalue = (index%13 + 1);
    suitvalue = (index / 13);

    switch (suitvalue) 
    {
        case 0: tsuit = "Hearts";
            break;
        case 1: tsuit = "Diamonds"; 
            break;
        case 2: tsuit = "Clubs";
            break;
        case 3: tsuit = "Spades";
            break;
    }
    switch (facevalue)
    {
        case 1: tface = "Ace";
            tvalue = 1;
            break;
        case 11: tface = "Jack";
            tvalue = 10;
            tfacebool = true;
            break;
        case 12: tface = "Queen";
            tvalue = 10;
            tfacebool = true;
            break;
        case 13: tface = "King";
            tvalue = 10;
            tfacebool = true;
            break;  
    }

    if ((facevalue > 1) && (facevalue < 11))
        tface = to_string(facevalue);
    if (facevalue < 11) tvalue = facevalue; 

    thand.card[i].suit = tsuit; 
    thand.card[i].face = tface;
    thand.card[i].value = tvalue;
    thand.card[i].facebool = tfacebool;
    }
    return thand;

    }

points calcvalue(player player1, player house)
{
    points tpoints;

    player1.sum = ((player1.hand.card[1].value +                    player1.hand.card[2].value +                    player1.hand.card[3].value) % 10);

    if (player1.hand.card[1].facebool == true &&        player1.hand.card[2].facebool == true &&        player1.hand.card[3].facebool == true)
    player1.sum = 10;

    house.sum = ((house.hand.card[1].value +                        house.hand.card[2].value +                      house.hand.card[3].value) % 10);

    if (house.hand.card[1].facebool == true &&      house.hand.card[2].facebool == true &&      house.hand.card[3].facebool == true)
        house.sum = 10;

        tpoints.player1 = player1.sum;
        tpoints.player2 = house.sum;

        return tpoints;
}

int winner(player player1, player house){
    int winorlose;

    if (player1.sum > house.sum)
        {winorlose = 1;}
        else if (player1.sum < house.sum) 
        {winorlose = -1;;}
        else if (player1.sum == house.sum)
        {winorlose = 0;}
        return winorlose;

}
```

Comment: don't make us count lines. point out WHERE line 60 is...

Comment: What happened when you debugged it?

Comment: @RyanP I have a cout << "check"; right after the problem and it never outputs anything. (my IDE is coderunner, which doesn't have full debug features)

Comment: @AustinR have you tried making a test integer before the cin statement, and replacing `cin >> player1.bet;` with `cin >> test;`?

Comment: The problem is not at line 60. You cannot see the "check" afterwards because it isn't flushed (try `cout << "check" << flush`), the program hangs afterwards, in `drawhand`. This is not a good algorithm to draw a hand... try it as you would do in real life, shuffling the whole deck and taking cards afterwards.

Comment: @RyanP I just tried that, same thing happens.

Comment: @vukung I missed the back half of your comment... Where would I find an algorithm to shuffle the cards like you suggest?

Comment: Smells like an assignment so,[random_shuffle] (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) is probably out. Go old school. and do it the way you would by hand. Take a random number of cards off the top of the deck. Reinsert the cards at some random point in the deck. Repeat until satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

I see a lot of problems at first glance actually.  eg: You've called a hand object 'hand' (thus redefining it), if you're going to call your object names the same as their class/struct, at least differentiate them with capitalization.  eg: call your hand struct "Hand" instead of "hand"

```
            cout << "What do you want to bet? ";

            cin  >> player1.bet;  //                      <====  problem              
            cout << "check";
            if (player1.bet < player1.money){

            }
            else if (player1.bet > player1.money){
                cout << "\nYou cannot go into debt!!\n";
            }
            else if (player1.bet == 0){
                cout << "\nYou ended the game!";
                return 0;
            }
```

That being said the issue you are having specifically relating to this section of code probably has something to do with a "\n" staying in the buffer and not getting cleared.  Try using cin.ignore(numeric_limits::max(),'\n');  to solve this problem (don't forget to #include limits as well).

Similar problem here: [c++ cin input not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5877420/c-cin-input-not-working)

Unfortunately I'm pressed for time and don't have time for a thorough look. :(